# What should I do if I can't vote to delete because the question has duplicates, but they are off-topic?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-delete

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification) has already accumulated 8 delete votes, which seems to be fair enough.

But when I tried to cast a delete vote to *actually* delete it, I couldn't, because the question is the duplicate target for [many questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/728260?lq=1).

All those questions are off-topic and are asking "How to do it" with most questions asking for tools and being primarily opinion-based.

What can be done to resolve this situation?

Also, if I'm not allowed to delete questions which are linked with duplicates, then why is the <kbd>delete</kbd> option shown for them in the first place?

Comment: did you consider voting to delete duplicates? (that's what I usually do at another site where I have 10K)

Comment: @honk: Was it really necessary to draw extra attention to this old question by editing it?

Comment: @Cerbrus this question can now be closed, because the question it is about is deleted in the meantime.

Comment: The linked question has accumulated some undelete-votes, though :-/

Comment: (At leas one of them being cast since this question was edited. It was at 5 votes at that moment.)

___Do not undelete-vote that question!___ It's a blatant tool request, and really has no business being on SO.

Comment: @Cerbrus: I'm sorry to have caused some annoyance. I just found the problem raised in this question interesting and saw some room for improvement. IMHO this question addresses a general problem, although a specific question is linked. I didn't expect that Meta folks start doing stupid things because of my edit...

Comment: @honk: that's okay. Just make sure to consider if drawing extra attention to an old post is necessary or not, next time. :-)

Comment: @Cerbrus: Got it. I will try to be more cautious with old questions that address specific posts.